# What's the reason for this compile error? "Property containerElement does not exist on type IntrinsicAttributes & TabProps..."

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, material-ui, typescript2.0

I am trying to build tabs for navigation on top of my React app, snippet like the following. I am using Typescript for this.

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import Tabs from '@material-ui/core/Tabs';
import Tab from '@material-ui/core/Tab';
...
<Router>
  <Tabs onChange={this.changeTab} value='false' >
    <Tab value = '0' label="Index"  containerElement={<Link to="/index"/>} />
    <Tab value = '1' label="About"  containerElement={<Link to="/about"/>} />                   
  </Tabs>
</Router>
```

And the compiler told me the following error, I don't know why the above Link works in ES6 version of the app, but does not work in Typescript version. Is there a way to fix it?

```
(32,37): Property 'containerElement' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & TabProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
```

**[EDIT ]Add additional Info:**

Show the info in my package.json file related to this discussion:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^1.2.3",
    ...
   }
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/material-ui": "^0.21.3",
    ...
   }
```

Comment: Do you use latest `@types/material-ui` typings?

Comment: @AlekseyL. Hasn't   `import Tabs from '@material-ui/core/Tabs' ` made the above app use latest @types/material-ui typings? 

Here is the a line for material-ui in the devDependencies block inside my package.json     "@types/material-ui": "^0.20.8",

Comment: Could you try to upgrade to `0.21.3`? It is strange because `containerElement` is definitely part of `TabProps`

Comment: @AlekseyL. Yes, just updated by `npm install --save-dev @types/material-ui@latest`, which made the package up to 0.21.3. However, the error still stays here

Comment: @chen Try to import them this way "import {Tabs, Tab} from 'material-ui/Tabs';"

Comment: @PaoloDell'Aguzzo, After doing the change you suggested, the error message became `Module not found: Can't resolve 'material-ui/Tabs' in '/Users/chen/learning/reactproject/src' `

Comment: @chen You should try to edit the typescript declaration file (extension .d.ts) for material-ui Tab. Probably they missed to declare the prop containerElement. I can see that in the past month there have been some issues about missing props for typescript in material-ui :)